# Shape Recognition with GPUImage

Tags: ios, macos, gpuimage

In general I want to check if a image contains a special logo.

So I used the GPUImage framework to do corner detection. See the image:

[image]

In this example image you can see a logo at the left top corner:

[image]

How can I achieve to compare whether this logo is contained by an image? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance and best regards from Germany
Chris

Comment: sound like a job for [OpenCV](http://opencv.org).

Comment: Can you give some further details please? a Tutorial or something similar Thanks

Comment: no, never used it. but you could ask google.